# Remove the parent tag in sgml using java if it has the specific tag inside it

Tags: java, regex, parsing, sgml

i want to remove the parent tag , if the tag has only note tag in it.

Example :

Input:

```
<data>
<subdata>
<l1item>
    <note>
        <para>hello
        </para>
    </note>
</l1item>
</subdata>
<subdata>
<l2item>
    <para> dont delete 
    </para>
</l2item>
<l3item>
    <note>
        <para>hello
        </para>
    </note>
    <para> dont delete 
    </para>
</l3item>
</subdata>
</data>
```

Expected Output:

```
<data>
<subdata>
<note>
<para>hello
</para>
</note>
</subdata>
<subdata>
<l2item>
<para> dont delete 
</para>
</l2item>
<l3item>
    <note>
        <para>hello
        </para>
    </note>
    <para> dont delete 
    </para>
</l3item>
</subdata>
</data>
```

In the above example the l1item tag is deleted has it has only note tag in it , l2item is not deleted as it has para tag and l3item is not deleted as it has note tag and para tag

so my requirement is like i want to delete the l1item or l2item or l3item if it has only note tag in it , and if it has some other tag or note tag with some other tag that should not be deleted.

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt).  Java's implementation of it is the [Transformer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html) class.

Comment: i looked on xslt , i think it will be harder to remove the parent element if the only note child exits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jsoup here although it's not *primarily* an SGML parser.

We are looking for `note` elements that are the only child of their respective parent. This can be translated as:

```css
note:only-child
```

When we spot one of those notes, we can find its parent and replace this parent with the found note. We'll use the [`Node::replaceWith`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#replaceWith-org.jsoup.nodes.Node-) method for doing this:

```java
foundNote.parent().replaceWith(foundNote);
```

Let's putting all together in the sample code below:

#### SAMPLE CODE

```java
String sgml = "<data>\n<subdata>\n<l1item>\n    <note>\n        <para>hello\n        </para>\n    </note>\n</l1item>\n</subdata>\n<subdata>\n<l2item>\n    <para> dont delete \n    </para>\n</l2item>\n<l3item>\n    <note>\n        <para>hello\n        </para>\n    </note>\n    <para> dont delete \n    </para>\n</l3item>\n</subdata>\n</data>";

Document doc = Parser.xmlParser().parseInput(sgml, "");

System.out.println("BEFORE:\n" + doc.html());

Elements onlyChildNotes = doc.select("note:only-child");

for (Element note : onlyChildNotes) {
    Element noteParent = note.parent();
    if (noteParent != null) {
        noteParent.replaceWith(note);
    }
}

System.out.println("AFTER:\n" + doc.html());
```

#### OUTPUT

```
BEFORE:
<data> 
 <subdata> 
  <l1item> 
   <note> 
    <para>
     hello 
    </para> 
   </note> 
  </l1item>
 </subdata>
  (...)

AFTER:
<data> 
 <subdata> 
  <note> 
   <para>
    hello 
   </para> 
  </note> 
 </subdata> 
 (...)
```

Comment: but if i give the data in capital's , it is parsing automatically to lower case

Comment: @Karthick If you need help on the "lower case" issue, post a new question.

Comment: anything we can do with java regex or something ?, because jsoup changes the sgml format